# what is the major difference between operators publish() and map in Reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

I had read the java doc but i have no idea about the major usage scenarios

here is  doc ;

```java
    /**
     * Share a {@link Mono} for the duration of a function that may transform it and
     * consume it as many times as necessary without causing multiple subscriptions
     * to the upstream.
     *
     * @param transform the transformation function
     * @param <R> the output value type
     *
     * @return a new {@link Mono}
     */
    public final <R> Mono<R> publish(Function<? super Mono<T>, ? extends Mono<? extends
            R>> transform) {
        return onAssembly(new MonoPublishMulticast<>(this, transform));
    }
```

I tried the unit test  code snippet below

```java
    @Test
    public void publish(){
        Mono<String> publish = Mono.just("test")
                .doOnNext(s -> log.info("publish --- {}",s))
                .publish(mo -> mo.map(e->e+"add String"))
                .doOnNext(s -> log.info("publish --- {}",s))
                ;

        Mono<String> map = Mono.just("test")
                .doOnNext(s -> log.info("publish --- {}", s))
                .publish(mo -> mo.map(e -> e + "add String"))
                .map(s -> s + "add String");

   }
```

The `publish` seems like  no difference  with `map` ,  both of them usage is trans the specify object to another type or value which is in same stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a situation, where you are producing something from an asynchronous function and the output is being consumed multiple times by different subscribers. In normal cases, the asynchronous function would be invoked each time a new subscriber joins.

```
 Supplier<Mono<String>> supplier = () -> {
        System.out.println("invoke");
        return Mono.just("nothing");
    };
 Mono<String> mono = Mono.defer(supplier);
 mono.subscribe();  //prints 'invoke'
 mono.subscribe();  //again prints 'invoke'
```

However, if you don't want to invoke the upstream publisher for subsequent subscribers and optionally want some transformation on the original Mono, you can use publish method. (See the below snippet)

```
Mono<String> m2 = Mono.defer(supplier).publish(stringMono -> {
          // Optionally can do some transformation.
            stringMono.subscribe();  // prints 'invoke'
            stringMono.subscribe();  // nothing printed
            stringMono.subscribe();  // nothing printed
            return stringMono;
        });
```

Here, 'invoke' is printed only single times although we call **subscribe** 3 times. That's because, call to the upstream is made only once.